# How to unit test a javascript object with value?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, fs, ts-jest

I have a js file where i read some value and load the results into a variable . the benefit i get is i dont have to read from file everytime i need it . i can simply import the object and use it.

however i dont know how to write unit test for it.

```
    const fs = require('fs');


const read_file = (path) => {
  try {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error in read_file', err);
    throw err;
  }
};

const getSecret = secretName => {
  try {
    return read_file(`/etc/secrets/${secretName}.txt`);
  } catch (err){
    throw err;
  }
};

const secretConfig = {
  kafka_keystore_password: getSecret('kafka_keystore_password')
};

module.exports = secretConfig;
```

i use jest to write test cases.

i have tried something like this , but still the object resolves to undefined.

```
const secretConfig = require('./secret');
const fs = require('fs');
jest.mock('fs');
fs.readFileSync.mockReturnValue('randomPrivateKey');


 

describe('secret read files', () => {
    
  it('should read secret from file', async () => {
    const secretMessage = secretConfig.kafka_keystore_password;
    expect(secretMessage).toEqual('randomPrivateKey');

  })

})
```

> > secret read files › should read secret from file
>
> ```
> expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
>
> Expected: "randomPrivateKey"
> Received: undefined
>
>   18 |     const secretMessage = secretConfig.kafka_keystore_password;
>   19 |     //expect(fs.readFileSync).toHaveBeenCalled();
> > 20 |     expect(secretMessage).toEqual('randomPrivateKey');
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is correct. The problem is that you need to mock before `require` the `./secret` module because the `getSecret` method will be executed immediately when the module is required. At this time, the `fs.readFileSync` has not been given a mocked value yet.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFileSync.mockReturnValue('randomPrivateKey');
const secretConfig = require('./secret');

jest.mock('fs');

describe('secret read files', () => {
  it('should read secret from file', async () => {
    const secretMessage = secretConfig.kafka_keystore_password;
    expect(secretMessage).toEqual('randomPrivateKey');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
> jest "-o" "--coverage"

 PASS  examples/69283738/secret.test.js (7.265 s)
  secret read files
    ✓ should read secret from file (2 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |   76.92 |      100 |     100 |   76.92 |                   
 secret.js |   76.92 |      100 |     100 |   76.92 | 8-9,17            
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.794 s
```

Comment: quick question : how long the variable  secretConfig.kafka_keystore_password will be available on memory ? whats the scope of that object ? this application is expressJS  controller with nodejs environment

Comment: @amarnathharish This variable remains in memory until the nodejs process exits. Whether the application is an express web server or a general script program. For testing, It's a JS script. The test runner will collect the use cases to be tested, and the program will be executed once, and will not run for a long time like a web server. I am not sure what you mean about "what's the scope of that object"

Comment: if i understand correcly once the node application starts upon first require/import statement only the file will be read , for subsequent request the object secretConfig will have the value 'randomwPrivateKey' ?  even if the scope of the object secretConfig is changed to 'let' instead of 'const' ?? also  if i have to write one more test case in same secre.test.js file it would still have the value 'randomPrivatekey' ? how do i test for error scenario then ?

Comment: @amarnathharish [require.cache](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache), Modules are cached in this object when they are required. For this scenario, you should use [jest.doMock()](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) and [jest.resetModules()](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules) to clear the module cache for each test case. You can try it first, if you have question, ask a new one.